# I have an error for an sql close statement and cant find out how to fix it

Tags: php-7

So i'm working on a login ("https://howcoolitis.net/login") and im having this issue with an sql close statement which prevents the user from registering. What should I fix, this sql statement say that it doesn't recognize $stmt as sql.

I have tried changing all the variables so they dont match with others but it made it worse, This is on PHP 7.3.1 I believe.

```php
<?php
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: https://howcoolitis.net/home");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";
$discord_err = "";
$discord = "";
$email = "";
$email_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $discord = $_POST['discord'];
    // Validate username
    if (empty(trim($discord))){
        $discord_err = "Please enter your discord.";
        $username_err = " ";
        $password_err = " ";
        $confirm_password_err = " ";
        $email_err = " ";
    }
    else{
        $username = strtok($discord, '#');
        if (strlen($username) > 32){
            $discord_err = "That cant be a discord username!";
            $username_err = " ";
            $password_err = " ";
            $confirm_password_err = " ";
            $email_err = " ";
        } // home
        if (strlen($username) < 2){
            $discord_err = "That cant be a discord username!";
            $username_err = " ";
            $password_err = " ";
            $confirm_password_err = " ";
            $email_err = " ";
        }
        if (($pos = strpos($discord, "#")) !== FALSE) { 
            $whatIWant = substr($discord, $pos+1); 
        }
        else{
            $discord_err = "Please type your discord tag!";
            $username_err = " ";
            $password_err = " ";
            $confirm_password_err = " ";
            $email_err = " ";
        }
        if (strlen($whatIWant) != 4){
            $discord_err = "That can't be a discord tag!";
            $username_err = " ";
            $password_err = " ";
            $confirm_password_err = " ";
            $email_err = " ";
        }
        if (!is_numeric($whatIWant)){
            $discord_err = "That can't be a discord tag!";
            $username_err = " ";
            $password_err = " ";
            $confirm_password_err = " ";
            $email_err = " ";
        }
    }
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username!";
        $discord_err = " ";
        $password_err = " ";
        $confirm_password_err = " ";
        $email_err = " ";
    } 
    if (empty(trim($email))){
        $email_err = "Please enter your email!";
        $username_err = " ";
        $password_err = " ";
        $confirm_password_err = " ";
        $discord_err = " ";
    }
    else{
        if (($pos = strpos($email, "@")) !== FALSE) { 
        }
        else{
            $email_err = "Please enter a valid email!";
            $username_err = " ";
            $password_err = " ";
            $confirm_password_err = " ";
            $discord_err = " ";
        }
        if (($pos = strpos($email, ".")) !== FALSE) { 
        }
        else{
            $email_err = "Please enter a valid email!";
            $username_err = " ";
            $password_err = " ";
            $confirm_password_err = " ";
            $discord_err = " ";
        }
    }
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        if (($pos = strpos($email, "@")) !== FALSE) { 
            $emailsql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ?";

            if($emailstmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $emailsql)){
                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($emailstmt, "s", $param_email);

                // Set parameters
                $paaram_email = trim($_POST["email"]);

                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($emailstmt)){
                    /* store result */
                    mysqli_stmt_store_result($emailstmt);

                    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($emailstmt) == 1){
                        $email_err = "This email is already used.";
                    } else{
                        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
            }
            mysqli_stmt_close($emailstmt);
        }
         else{
             $email_err = "Incorrect email!";
         }
        // Close statement

        $discord = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE discord = ?";

        if($stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "s", $param_discord);

            // Set parameters
            $param_discord = trim($_POST["discord"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt1);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt1) == 1){
                    $discord_err = "This discord is already binded to an account";
                } else{
                    $discord = trim($_POST["discord"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt1);
    }

    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";   
        $username_err = " ";
        $confirm_password_err = " ";
        $discord_err = " ";
        $email_err = " ";  
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
        $username_err = " ";
        $password_err = " ";
        $confirm_password_err = " ";
        $discord_err = " ";
        $email_err = " ";
    }
    else if (strlen($_POST['username']) > 20){
        $username_err = "Username can not be bigger than 20 characters.";
        $password_err = " ";
        $confirm_password_err = " ";
        $discord_err = " ";
        $email_err = " ";
    } 
    else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";   
        $discord_err = " ";
        $email_err = " ";
        $password_err = " ";
        $username_err = " ";  
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
            $discord_err = " ";
            $email_err = " ";
            $password_err = " ";
            $username_err = " ";  
        }
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err) && empty($discord_err)){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, discord, Email, IMG_DIR, ProfileBio, License1, License2, License3, License4, Friends, EmailVerfication, ExtraOption, Banned, Deleted, IpAdress, ExtraOption2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_discord, $param_email);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_discord = strtolower($discord);
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $to = $email;

                $subject = 'Thank You For Registering with HCII';

                $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                $message = '<html><body>';
                $message .= '<h1>Thank You For Registering!<br><br><br>Have A good one! <a href = "https://howcoolitis.net/login">Click here to login</a></h1>';
                $message .= '</body></html>';
                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                // Store data in session variables
                $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                $_SESSION["username"] = $username; 
                $_SESSION['discord'] = $discord;                           
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                // Redirect user to welcome page
                header("location: https://howcoolitis.net/home");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HCII - Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://howcoolitis.net/style.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body id = "particles-js">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>HCII - Sign Up</h2>
        <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $email_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($discord_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Discord</label>
                <input type="text" name="discord" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $discord; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $discord_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
            </div>
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="https://howcoolitis.net/login">Login here</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>    
    <script src = "https://howcoolitis.net/script.js"></script>
        <script src = "https://howcoolitis.net/app.js"></script>
        <style> .wrapper{; background-color:white; position: absolute; width: 520px; height: 600px; border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); } </style>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought that it was of the sql query being named the same as others but it didnt work.

Do you guys know what I should do? Im new to StackOverFlow and php in general.

Sorry if I typed this wrong its my first time.

EDIT: I pasted the full code.

Comment: you can actually see the error for yourself at https://howcoolitis.net/register if I have not fixed it yet.

Comment: are you opening the connection at all?

Comment: yes, I opened the connection, it worked before but it just stopped working now.

Comment: im pretty sure there is something wrong in this area.

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: this is the error: arning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\register\index.php on line 282

Comment: you could also see it on https://howcoolitis.net/register

Comment: Its made to be a register system

Comment: If you want I can paste the full code because I think the connection details are in another file.

Comment: ok, you're database is open you have a boolean field that you are not providing with a boolean parameter

Comment: I think I know what is causing that in the code I believe ill go test it out.

Comment: By boolean, you mean a if statement or a true or false variable>

Comment: a field in your table is a boolean, guess in this line $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, discord, Email, IMG_DIR, ProfileBio, License1, License2, License3, License4, Friends, EmailVerfication, ExtraOption, Banned, Deleted, IpAdress, ExtraOption2) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')";

Comment: I understand now.

Comment: Thank You So Much!!! It Worked!